# error in #include <QFtp> what should i do

Tags: qt, ftp, qftp

I want to use ftp from my Qt project. But when I add `#include <QFtp>` in the program and run
the compiler says: "error: QFtp: No such file or directory".

Comment: You seem not to have selected an answer, nor did you provide critics for my answer. What more can we do for you? What is missing?

Answer (score 4):

You should add something like this, to your project file.

```
QT += network
```

[QFtp](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qftp.html) is part of [Network module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtnetwork.html)

Comment: thanks   but i added it before :( the problem should be anythings else!!

Comment: What SDK do you use? I assumed that you are using Qt 4.x, because of QFtp class. But QFtp class was removed from Qt 5.x ( reason: flaw design )

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the qmake statement below in your qmake project file (.pro or .pri) with Qt 5 as it was moved to a separate playground module due to its design limitations. However, I have used it successfully in my previous commercial project, so it should be fine:

```
QT += ftp
```

Otherwise, if you are still using Qt 4, you just need to include the `network` module into the `QT` variables as seen below:

```
QT += network
```

Comment: I'm using QT 5.4.2 and QT += ftp gives me a message: "Unknown module(s) in QT: ftp"

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88 yeah, you should be installing the module. Of course if you don't have it installed, it doesn't exist… no reason to downvote this answer just because you have no idea how to install stuff!

Comment: You didn't explain it well. That's good enough reason to downvote someone dontcha think?

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88 um, nope?

Comment: Sucks. Improve your answer and maybe that down vote will go away

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88 "your answer"? it's not my answer. The author of the answer has been suspended so he hasn't a chance to edit it. Apply your common sense, dude.

Comment: It's still not a good answer -- it should be down voted.... If he linked to the module and showed how to add then it would get an up vote. I don't really see what your problem is with my down vote. It's NOT a good answer or at least not good enough to stand on it's own -- the down-vote is a mechanism to get the user to give a better response or highlight other responses that could be better.

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88 The up-vote is a mechanism to tease down-voters ;)